# How do I get the Solaris-8 patch to fix the missing SOL_TCP in /usr/include/sys/socket.h?

Tags: solaris

Porting an application from RHEL5 to Solaris 8.
setsockopt(kinet[inst_id].sock_no,SOL_TCP,TCP_NODELAY,&option,sizeof(option));
causes a compile error because SOL_TCP is not defined in /usr/include/sys/socket.h in Solaris 8, as it is in RHEL5.

Answer (score 1):

SOL_TCP is not portable, but it looks like you get it to working on Solaris and others by adding this:

```
#ifndef SOL_TCP
#define SOL_TCP IPPROTO_TCP
#endif
```